# How to set webview client?

Tags: android

I seen in android documentation  where you use

```
 private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
```

To handle when items are clicked within a webview.

The only problem is with me, is that im setting the url in another method.

The HelloWebViewClient overrides that and doesnt use the url that the user can chose from. It just returns null..How could i over ride this method to use the url set by the user?

The URL is loaded when i use it in a regular method with the `WebView browser;` and then `browser.loadUrl(String url)`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shopping);

    findIT = (Button)findViewById(R.id.findIT);
    edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.item);
    type = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.console);
    site = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.shopping_group);

    findIT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            item = edittext.getText().toString();
                lookUp();
        }
    });

}

public void lookUp(){

    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.shoppingBrowser);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Log.v(item, item);
    getUserPreference();
    browser.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    browser.loadUrl(url);


}



  private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String notuse) {
        Log.v("shopping", url+" loaded");



       return true;
    }


  }
public void getUserPreference(){

    switch(type.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
    case R.id.item:
        console = "item";
        break;
    case R.id.PS3:
        console = "item";
        break;
    case R.id.item:
        console = "item"; 
        break;

    }Log.v("item", console);
     switch(site.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){

         case R.id.store:
             url = "http://www.gamestop.com/browse?nav=16k- "+ item +"  " + console;
             break;
         case R.id.store:
             url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+item + "   " + console+"&tbm=shop&hl=en&aq=0&oq=where+";
             break;
         case R.id.store:
             url = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dvideogames&field-keywords="+item + "  "+ console+"&x=0&y=0"; 
             Log.v("shopping", url);
          }
       }
  }
```

If you see what im trying to do the user gets to select what site they want to shop from. and from there i set it to the url.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the user is choosing the URL from the same activity you can just reference the URL from the member variable instead of the URL from the parameter:

```
// Member variable stored to reflect user's choice
private String mUserUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // This line right here is what you're missing.
        // Use the url provided in the method.  It will match the member URL!
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This tells the WebviewClient that you've overloaded the URL loading (and in fact caused it to load the URL that you wish instead of the url supplied).

Here is a complete example of something I mocked up:

```
public class HelloWebViewActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView = null;
    private EditText mInputUrl = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mInputUrl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_url);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              String url = mInputUrl.getText().toString();
              mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps.  If this works for you please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Its not what im actually trying to do. Check out my edit above.

Comment: Please note that this method is currently deprecated

Answer (score 7):

It isn't clear from your question whether this is the case, but it is possible that you did not set the WebViewClient of your WebView to the custom subclass that you created in your code. Somewhere in your code you should have something like:

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

If you are only doing this with this one instance of WebView and your modifications to the WebViewClient are simple, then I would suggest that a more elegant way to accomplish this would be the following:

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // Insert your code here
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

Is it possible that the WebViewClient is actually a red herring? It appears to me that there is a problem with your switch statements in getUserPreference(). While the first switch statement seems unnecessary, the second one only ever sets the url to gamestop because all of your cases are the same.

Comment: The user has a choice to pick between urls. The problem is the url in String URL wont accept the url im trying to give to it to load in the webview

Comment: I just edited my response to show what's missing, but it's in the edit queue so I'll try to explain here too:  in shouldOverrideUrlLoading() you should have the following lines: view.loadUrl(url); // This is the member variable url
            return true;

Comment: It helps if I edit my **own** response instead of someone else's.  Sorry glorifiedHacker... not my intent at all.

Answer (score 0):

You will set your custom `WebViewClient` for your webview and load the url in the webview as you we're doing before:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HellowWebViewClient());
mWebView.loadUrl(yourUrl);
```

Comment: Everytime a item is clicked it refers back to the (yourUrl)

Comment: I can't understand the behaviour from your comment. Put more code and be more specific in what you are trying to achieve please.