# Webview - change page source before show website?

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I have a website. On the Website, there is a text "Pic". When I show the website in the Webview for the first time I can change the text to "PicGreat". This works!

But, later when a user clicks on a Link (somewhere on the website), then I forward the user to the new HTML Website. Before I show the Website, I want to change the Text "Pic" to "PicGreat".

How can I make that? Should I write a function, and then call the function in
"public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading"?

I found a similar question here on Stackoverflow, but not solved.
[how to set webview client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850017/how-to-set-webview-client)

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/webview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

WebTest.java

```
public class WebTestActivity extends Activity {

 WebView mWebView;
 String rline = "";

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
 try
 {
 URL url = new URL("http://www.picSite.com/");
 urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in), 4096);
 String line;

 while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
 rline += line+"\n";
 }
 rd.close();

 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
 if ( null != urlConnection )
 {
 urlConnection.disconnect();
 }
 }

 String getNewCode = rline.replace("Pic", "PicGreat");

 mWebView.loadData(getNewCode, "text/html", "utf-8");

 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
 }

 private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
 view.loadUrl(url);
 return true;
 }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)):

> Notify the host application of a resource request and allow the
>   application to return the data. If the return value is null, the
>   WebView will continue to load the resource as usual. Otherwise, the
>   return response and data will be used.
>
> NOTE: This method is called on
>   a thread other than the UI thread so clients should exercise caution
>   when accessing private data or the view system.

Comment: fro the javadoc of shouldInterceptRequest, it says it returns A WebResourceResponse containing the response information or null if the WebView should load the resource itself. I don't see how it it related with rewriting the html.

Comment: @kevin You could load page by yourself, rewrite its source and return it as `WebResourceResponse`.