# How can I embed a website in my app

Tags: android

I am currently creating an app, only now I have got to a point where I would like to be able to embed a website into the actual app itself. The thing is I would like to be able to view the website without leaving the app, so it is embedded into the app somehow. I am realising that this might not be as easy as it sounds as it almost needs a browser, though I don't really need to do any browsing as such, I only need to load the site and then display it. Is this even possible (isn't anything possible?)

Thanks!

Comment: @parag : the user has only 1 question before this one.. I think its OK..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set webview client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850017/how-to-set-webview-client)